# Show "UNDER CONSTUCTION" page if application is undeployed

Tags: tomcat

Is it possible to show page "UNDER CONSTRUCTION" when an application is undeployed? And how?
Tnx.

Answer (score 2):

There is no default setting for that, however an undeployed application will cause a 404 http status **at the default context** (url: "/", directory: "ROOT"). So if you deploy a dummy application at webapps/ROOT and handle the appropriate error you can redirect to different pages. Here is a web.xml you can use as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="UndeployedAppInfo" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns /javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>UndeployedInfo</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>info.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/undeployed.html</location>
</error-page>
<!-- add more error pages here ... -->

</web-app>
```

Of course other page not found errors, caused by dead links in your deployed applications, will also be redirected, if you dont create error-page elements in your app, to overwrite these.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have real deployed application while Tomcat always have default existing homepage.

With `CATALINA_HOME` is Tomcat directory,  you change default homepage file at `%CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\ROOT\index.jsp` . Change content to what you want (Underconstruction information).

[image]
(View the above image in new windows for bigger size)